# MySQL suddenly crashed

Tags: mysql

MySQL suddenly crashed. PHP shows error: 
`Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory`

```
[root@support mysql]# mysql -v
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

- Checked storage details are all good (df -h & df -i)
- The socket file seems okay (i stopped the service & deleted the lock file) [image]
- Error log:
  `2020-03-03T04:11:10.160439Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: './zabbix_bk/widget_field.ibd' OS error: 71
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.160451Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.160463Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.160474Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.160487Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for`zabbix_bk/widget_field`. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.160500Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace`zabbix_bk/widget_field`because it could not be opened.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.162306Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.162331Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.162573Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.175636Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.176919Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.176949Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.178519Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.23 started; log sequence number 9654599972
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.179611Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.179951Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.181546Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/plugin from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
  mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.181662Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.182789Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/gtid_executed from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
  mysqld: Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' doesn't exist
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.182854Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.182909Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.183401Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.187590Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.187676Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.187712Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.187778Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.189608Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200303 12:11:10
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.189888Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/server_cost from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.189931Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.191998Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/time_zone_leap_second from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.192053Z 0 [Warning] Can't open and lock time zone table: Table 'mysql.time_zone_leap_second' doesn't exist trying to live without them
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.192946Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/servers from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.192980Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.203770Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 1 event
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.204582Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
  Version: '5.7.23-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
  2020-03-03 12:11:10 0x7efd135fe700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139625416877824 in file btr0cur.cc line 325
  InnoDB: Failing assertion: btr_page_get_next( latch_leaves.blocks[0]->frame, mtr) == page_get_page_no(page)
  InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
  InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
  InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
  InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
  InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
  InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
  InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
  04:11:10 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
  This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
  or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
  or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
  Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
  As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
  collection process might fail.
  key_buffer_size=8388608
  read_buffer_size=131072
  max_used_connections=0
  max_threads=151
  thread_count=0
  connection_count=0
  It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
  key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68195 K  bytes of memory
  Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
  Thread pointer: 0x7efd040008c0
  Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
  where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
  terribly wrong...
  stack_bottom = 7efd135fddd8 thread_stack 0x40000
  /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0xf52f35]
  /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x4a4)[0x7d3754]
  /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf7e0)[0x7efd759167e0]
  /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7efd743b64f5]
  /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x7efd743b7cd5]
  /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z18ut_print_timestampP8_IO_FILE+0x0)[0x7c28a8]
  /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z20btr_cur_latch_leavesP11buf_block_tRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP9btr_cur_tP5mtr_t+0x7ac)[0x11ba89c]
  /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z27btr_cur_search_to_nth_levelP12dict_index_tmPK8dtuple_t15page_cur_mode_tmP9btr_cur_tmPKcmP5mtr_t+0x233b)[0x11c7adb]
  /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z22row_search_index_entryP12dict_index_tPK8dtuple_tmP10btr_pcur_tP5mtr_t+0x13b)[0x1120aeb]
  /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x111dbd9]
  /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z14row_purge_stepP9que_thr_t+0xa1d)[0x111fe9d]
  /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15que_run_threadsP9que_thr_t+0x9bf)[0x10d5a2f]
  /usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_worker_thread+0x100)[0x114faf0]
  /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7aa1)[0x7efd7590eaa1]
  /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7efd7446cc4d]
  Trying to get some variables.
  Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
  Query (0): is an invalid pointer
  Connection ID (thread ID): 0
  Status: NOT_KILLED
  The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
  information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.637453Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.23-log) starting as process 32491 ...
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.644182Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.644226Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.644239Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.644251Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.644263Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.644274Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.644682Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.644842Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.647913Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 1G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.748191Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.760371Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.765485Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.773068Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 9653793292
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.903199Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 9654600030
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.903438Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.903453Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
  2020-03-03T04:11:10.962458Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
  InnoDB: Progress in percent: 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 </code>`

Actually "zabbix_bk" had been removed for almost half a year??

Even I stopped the service, the error still logged into the error file(mysqld.log)?

OS: Centos 6
mySQL : 5.7.23

Thanks.

Comment: How was zabbix_bk removed? 5.7.23 has had a number of release fixes. Was there another mysql version used in this datadir? Did you run out of space at some point?

Comment: @danblack My colleague removed the particular DB folder manually. only one mysql version installed. no running out of space issue at this moment, 58% free space (147GB free).

Comment: and yes, i am using 5.7.23.

Comment: I temporary add the InnoDB recovery value to 2/3, and now I am able to access my database. But if i removed the recovery line, again it is failed to restart.

Comment: I suggest educating your colleague on the use of 'DROP DATABASE' and the importance of not touching mysql files directly. SInce you started with InnoDB recovery - take a full mysqldump, and restore to a fresh installation direction (mysql_install_db).

Comment: @danblack he said there are some errors happen when he tried to drop the DB. Lucky i am able to do a full backup, now need to reinstall the mysql as you suggested, i did some r&d, the mysql_install_db already deprecated.

Comment: @jack With recovery value of 2 or 3, and data is visible, take a full mysqldump of everything possible.  Do you have alternative equipment available to install 5.7.23 and begin the process of restoring the selective db/tables you need to keep?